# Create ElasticSearch dynamic template to ensure all fields are set to not_analyzed

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch type for which I want the mapping to be set dynamically. There are a few select fields on that type that I want to be analyzed, but everything else should be set to "not_analyzed".

I've come up with the following snippet. This sets all *string* fields to not be analyzed, but doesn't cover all other data types. I tried using the "generic" field shown in the documentation but it didn't help. Can anyone tell me how I can accomplish this?

```
{
  "TypeName": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "template_name": {
          "match": "*",
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "index": "no",
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "dynamic": true,
    "properties": {
      "url": {
        "index": "analyzed",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "resourceUrl": {
        "index": "analyzed",
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "TypeName": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "base": {
            "mapping": {
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "dynamic": true,
      "properties": {
        "url": {
          "index": "analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "resourceUrl": {
          "index": "analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Overall, index-level template:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "base": {
            "mapping": {
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't seem to work. Every other string field is still being analyzed.

Comment: Do you have other templates defined?

Comment: No other templates. The problem I'm trying to get around is that I'm pushing a large amount of data into ElasticSearch and if it tries to analyze all of the fields then it throws an error.

Comment: That's impossible. That template is catching everything except `url` and `resourceUrl`. So, unless you have another template that takes precedence over the one defined above matching the type `test`, it's impossible.

Comment: Do you have multiple types for that index and not only `TypeName` as in your example?

Comment: Then you need index-level template. Updated.

Comment: Thanks. I also just discovered that strings are the only type that are analyzed anyway (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html)... so what I was trying to do was completely redundant.

Comment: Can i remove the "TypeName" if I don't have any types in the index?